# how get product data in custom product type on woocommerce loop?

Tags: woocommerce, product

my custom product type is : tour

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'product',
        'posts_per_page'    => 25,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'tour',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $products = new WP_Query($args);
```

how get custom product type data ( date and day and active/deactive and ... ) on woocommerce loop in top query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should Creating a Custom Product Type and adding Custom Fields to Product Settings .

Then to get those values you just need to use the popular `get_post_meta()` function. That’s pretty much all you need.

Example:

```
<?php

    // Display Custom Field Value
    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my-field-slug', true );

    // You can also use
    echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my-field-slug', true );
?>
```